# Trying to run JFLAP.jar in Fedora 23. Java is throwing exceptions

Tags: jar, fedora, java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:233)
    at gui.action.NewAction$NewDialog.<init>(NewAction.java:113)
    at gui.action.NewAction.showNew(NewAction.java:82)
    at gui.Main.main(Main.java:124)
    at JFLAP.main(JFLAP.java:57)
```

When trying to run the JFLAP.jar file by running `java -jar JFLAP.jar`. It's giving me the error above. When running `java -version` it tells me:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_71"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b15, mixed mode)
```

Any thoughts as to what's going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Let's begin by digging out the code that is causing the failure, assuming the link below is what you have in the JDK http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.java#161

Comment: Sorry about the late response. I put this issue on the back-burner for the time and ran into the same issue with a different jar file. after some extensive research, I came across a situation were a user only had the headless version of JRE installed. After checking to see which package I have installed, it turns out I only have the headless version of OpenJDK installed.